# Passing Lambda Variable to Glue Script AWS

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue

I have a lambda function that looks like this:

```
client = boto3.client('glue')

glueJobName = "Python Glue Script"
inputtedData = "A1B2C3D4E5"
school = "testing"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.start_job_run(JobName = glueJobName, Arguments = {'==inputtedData': inputtedData, '--school': school})
    return response
```

This starts running my glue job which contains a script. However, I want to pass the Arguments 'inputtedData' and 'school' to this script, so that when the script starts, these variables will be inputted into my syncData function like this:

```
def syncAttendance(inputtedData, school):

   schoolName = school
   Data = inputtedData
   print(schoolName, Data)


syncData(inputtedData, school)
```

How do I receive these variables in the glue script?

Comment: Note the typo in your `'==inputtedData'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getResolvedOptions` function as follows:

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

options = ['inputtedData', 'school']
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, options)

syncData(args['inputtedData'], args['school'])
```

Comment: Thanks, do I put this at the top of the python glue job script?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put `args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, options)`. It just needs to be executed before you call your `syncData`